# Copy large number of files of specific date to another directory?

Tags: grep, find, cp

I've around *11K* log files of specific date let say `26Feb` inside one directory(there are other date data also). To copy only `26th Feb` log files to destination from linux command line, I use below commands.

```
[root@achal logs]# ls -lrt | grep "Feb 26" | wc -l
11142
```

and

```
[root@achal logs]# find . -type f -newermt 'Feb 26' -exec cp {} 26Feb_UE_HISTORY/ \;
```

But it copies other date files also, not only 26th Feb files.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your selection finds all files **newer** than Feb 26. So you have to exclude the files modified after Feb 26:

```
find . -type f -newermt 'Feb 26' ! -newermt 'Feb 27' -exec cp {} 26Feb_UE_HISTORY/ \;
```

Comment: Thanks @muclux. It works perfectly.